# Many footnotes in table along same line with longtable split on two pages

Tags: tables, footnotes, ctable

I have a long table rotated of `90 degrees`, in which I want to insert about tens of `\footnote{a text}` (they are references to the bibliography for each row of the table, and the table has a few tens of rows). The table goes onto two pages, so that at some points it is automatically interrupted to make space to the references and then continues to the second page.

I am reading a few discussion on this topic, such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159678/table-footnotes-in-same-line) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line). However, they are not very useful in my case, probably because I am using a different class.The class I am using can be found [here.](https://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html#_download)

**EDIT: MWE**
Here is a MWE that shows what kind of environment I am using. However, my real table has tens of rows.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}\pdfoutput=1 
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apjfonts}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{threeparttablex, tablefootnote}
\usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}
\newcounter{mytempeqncnt}
\shorttitle{paper}
\shortauthors{authors}

\begin{document}
\title{paper}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{longrotatetable}
\begin{deluxetable*}{lllccccclll}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablecaption{Table 1\label{table1}}
\tablewidth{700pt}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Name1} & \colhead{Name2} & \colhead{Name3} & \colhead{Name4} & 
\colhead{Name5} & \colhead{Name6} & 
\colhead{Name7} & \colhead{Name8} & 
\colhead{Name9} & \colhead{Name10}  \\ 
\colhead{} & \colhead{} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & 
\colhead{(days)} & \colhead{(days)} &
\colhead{(days)} & \colhead{(degrees)} & \colhead{(degrees)} &     \colhead{} } 
\startdata
 &  &  & &  &  &   &  &  &  &   \\
 &  &  &    & \textbf{\normalsize New Names} &  &   &  &  &  &   \\
 &  &  &    &  &  &   &  &  &  &   \\
Name    & data  & n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7\footnote{A     Reference.}
 & $<10^{-3}$\footnote{Another reference.}
\enddata

\end{deluxetable*}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \small
  \item[a]{Note 1. a Reference} 
  \item[b] Note2. another reference
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{longrotatetable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

How do I get my references as footnotes on the same line (perhaps separated by a comma) under the table?
Again, consider that the table is long and rotated, so it goes on two pages. Therefore, part of the references will go under the table on the first page, while others on the second page.

Here is a picture of what I get with the MWE:
[image]

Comment: The two links you provide in your posting don't appear to point to what I would say is the obvious solution candidate: the `threeparttable` package, to be loaded with the `para` option to make all table notes run together in one big long paragraph (instead of each footnote starting on a new line). Please edit your posting to provide some more information about the mysterious "references for each line of the table" are: are they, essentially, footnote markers? If not, what are they?

Comment: Yes, footnote markers which I would nomaly addess as `\footnote{this text}`.

Comment: we will more easily help you if you will provide small but complete document called minimal working example (mwe), which will show, what you try so far and what you actually like to obtain.  `threeparttable` is good chaise for notes in table.

Comment: `threeparttablex` with the reference option is a bit easier. You can even set this up so that the notes are produced using a custom enumerate environment, such as one made with `enumitem`'s inline settings. This way, you don't have to hard-code note labels at all - it is all automatic. But, even without that, you only have to enter them manually once. Could do more with code, obviously. The code I've got might or might not work for you with a little adaption - hard to say.

Comment: Edited to add MWE

Comment: @cfr, are you writing an answer on that, or at least share some more details?

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't think it would work with `revtex`. That's why I said it was hard to say.

Comment: @cfr, On this empty thread, I suppose any try would be good :)

Comment: Yes, but it won't help if you need to use that class, will it?

Comment: That was just a MWE that rrepoduces the issue. I am not going to use the `revtex` class. Most likely I will use another scientific class, such as `article`.

Comment: i provide you answer which put all notes in form of paragraphs (in one line), but you say: is exactly what I wanted to avoid: to specify each and every note because that this is exactly what, as I said, I have many many footnotes. so i delete my answer ... however, what you now add to your question is  duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399985/ . please clarify, what actually you like to achieve.

Comment: @Zarko, you are right, I wanted to avoid inserting each and every note "by hand", but apparently there is no way to achieve that in my case. However, the notes still need to be put in sequence on the same line, which is not the case for the example page that you report. If you have answer for my case I will be happy to accept it, I apologize for former confusion.

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207975/indentation-problem-with-the-para-option-of-bigfoot

Comment: I have no idea what this question is now asking. What are the criteria for a satisfactory solution? In the comments, you say you'll use `article`, but then you complain solutions don't work with some other class. I don't know what you want to avoid doing for each note at all. It is easy to get `tablenotes` in a paragraph rather than one-per-line, but you've already seen how to do that. Your example only has one non-rotated page, but apparently two pages and rotation are crucial. A clear question with a pertinent MWE would be more likely to get an answer - you're just wasting a bounty.

Comment: @cfr, As I mentioned a few comments above, I tried to get something and after a month of research and questions I modified my code to get what I could. I have received no answers able to address my original request, so I asked for something on the same line but more keen to what was offered by the online mainstream.

Comment: As I say, I don't know what you're asking and it seems others are in the same boat. I've read your comments on the question and the answer, and I've read the question. I'm very sorry, but I no longer understand what you are trying to do or what an acceptable answer would be. Your MWE does not seem to reflect the situation you say you need to deal with and it is not clear what you are trying to avoid, though it is clear that there is something you want to avoid. So there isn't much to be done here at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

**edit:**

- i'm not familiar with `deluxetable*`, so i haven't solution how in it split table notes between pages. with `longtable` or `ltablex` this can be done as suggested [Mike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110842/mike) in his answer on [my similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399985/).
- to have notes in line, you only need to `tablenotes` add options the options `para` and (if you wish that notes start at left border of table) `flushleft` as you can see in old answer.
- considering this options in your mwe, gives the following result:

  ```
  \documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}\pdfoutput=1
  \usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage{apjfonts} %i haven't this fonts
  \usepackage{footnote}
  \usepackage{threeparttablex, tablefootnote}
  \usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}
  \newcounter{mytempeqncnt}
  \shorttitle{paper}
  \shortauthors{authors}

  \begin{document}
  \title{paper}
      \begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{longrotatetable}
  \begin{deluxetable*}{lllccccclll}
  % table body
  \end{deluxetable*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushright, para]\footnotesize
    \small
    \item[a]{Note 1. a Reference}
    \item[b] Note2. another reference
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{longrotatetable}
      \end{ThreePartTable}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

- in your table you beside table notes also use `footnote`s. if you like to have them on the botom of the page, their use ids fine, however, if you like to have for example below of table notes, than i suggest to write footnote as table note. for example, instead

  ```
  Name    & data  & n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7\footnote{A reference.}
   & $<10^{-3}$\footnote{Another reference.}
  \enddata
  \end{deluxetable*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushright, para]\footnotesize
    \item[1]  reference
    \item[2]  another reference
    \end{tablenotes}
  ```

  write for example

  ```
  Name    & data  & n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7\tnote{1}
   & $<10^{-3}$\tnote{2}
  \enddata
  \end{deluxetable*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushright, para]\footnotesize
    \item[1]  reference
    \item[2]  another reference
    \end{tablenotes}
  ```

  now the footnotes at bottom of page will be removes and your references will be (only) below of table:
- if you like to have solution for your table with `longtable` where 
  the table notes can be split between pages, let me know
- from your mwe (which has only fragment of table headers) can be concluded, that table can fit in normal portrait orientation. if this is not real case, please add on row more to table with some dummy content from which we can see the real table size.

[image]

**old answer:**

i'm guessing, that you try to obtain the following:

[image]

for this table i use `theeparttable`, `\tnote` and `tablenotes`

```
\documentclass{article}%[% reprint,]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[11]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.05}
\caption{\label{tab1}Table.}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
\textrm{Label}  &   \textrm{Value}          \\
    \hline
1               &   Value One\tnote{a}      \\
2               &   Value Two\tnote{b}      \\
3               &   Value Three\tnote{b}    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
    \item[a] test 1,
    \item[b] test 2,
    \item[b] test 3.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I wanted to avoid: to specify each and every note because, as I said, I have many many footnotes.

Comment: @Py-ser, and you believe, that with  use`\footnote{...}` you will have less work and better overlook on your table code? maybe. than my answer is not for you. you should wait on new one  ...

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. I can't test your code right now, I will do it soon. Are you sure that it works with my class, and long rotated, `deluxe*` tables?

Comment: i test your code and it works with my additions/changes (images of table is generated by it). however, my offer for `longtable` solution is still on table :-)

Comment: I am sorry, your code works well with a short table not split on two pages, which I was able to reach already. On two pages it works quite differently.

Comment: i make test with table long three page. and it works as expected. however, table notes are only on the last page. i show you solution with long table, with which you can do at each page (with same limitation).

Comment: I don't know how to do it better, but let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78211/tex-table)

Comment: Dear @Py-ser, sorry for late notice of your comment. today (night) i'm now to tired for chat. i will try to enjoy in chat ones tomorrow. i will call you back.

Comment: can you still help me with this? In your answer you said to let you know in case I need to split the notes between two pages for a `longtable` (I actually use `longrotatetable`).

Comment: oh, @Py-ser, after one year, i forgot all about your question and my answer :-(.  also you not accept my answer, so i conclude that it is not value to you, why now ask me for help? if i understand well your question in comment, than see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399985/.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93599/temporarytex)