# Issues with table footnote in one line

Tags: lyx, footnotes, threeparttable

I use `\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}` as suggested here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160113/231568) to try to display table footnotes in one line.
The size of the footnotes is controlled with `\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}`.
But the footnotes are not really displayed in one line as you can see in the following picture. There is e.g. still space after [a] and [c].
[image]

To display the notes in one line, I additionally tryed the command `[flushleft]`.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable} % threeparttable: to support table footnote, but this does not work correctly, looks ugly and footnotes are not displayed with fontsize footnotesize
\usepackage{booktabs} % booktabs: to support centering of table
\usepackage{etoolbox} % to support footnotesize within table
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize} % footnote font size within table
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{[\TPTtagStyle{#1}]}}} % brackets in table footnotes

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{Section one}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Lorem ipsum.\label{tab:Lorem-ipsum.}}

\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{1.2cm}>{\centering}m{3.5cm}>{\centering}m{2.5cm}>{\centering}m{2.5cm}>{\centering}m{2cm}}
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip0.1cm}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}a\tnote{a}} & \textbf{\footnotesize{}b} & \textbf{\footnotesize{}c} & \textbf{\footnotesize{}d\tnote{b}} & \textbf{\footnotesize{}g}\tabularnewline[0.1cm]
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip0.2cm}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}1\tnote{c}} &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}1\tnote{d}}{\footnotesize\par}

{\footnotesize{}2\tnote{d}}\tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}2\tnote{e}} &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}1\tnote{d}}{\footnotesize\par}

{\footnotesize{}2\tnote{d}}\tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}3\tnote{f}} &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}1\tnote{d}}\tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}4\tnote{e}} &  &  &  & \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}5} &  &  &  & \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}6\tnote{g}} &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}1\tnote{h}}\tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\textbf{\footnotesize{}7\tnote{i}} &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}1\tnote{h}}\tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Lorem 0.00 mmol sit amet, consetetur 0.00 mmol sed diam nonumy.
\item [b] Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
\item [c] Lorem 00 mol\% sit amet, consetetur 00 h elitr.
\item [d] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\item [e] Lorem ipsum 00 mol\% sit amet, consetetur 00 h elitr.
\item [f] Lorem dolor dolor sit amet.
\item [g] Lorem ipsum 00 mol\% sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
\item [h] Lorem ipsum dolor.
\item [i] Lorem ipsum 00 mol\% sit amet, consetetur  lorem ipsum dolor 000h sadipscing elitr.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With this the notes are displayed better in one line, but the notes have standard text size and not footnote size anymore.

[image]

How can I correct this? Footnotes clean alligned in one line, with footnote size?

Comment: You can add `\footnotesize` right after `\begin{tablenotes}`.

Comment: @Bernard I tried this out. This is not working. The footnotes are in footnote size if I use `\footnotesize` right after `\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]`. But then I have again the issue which is displayed in my first picture.

Comment: Could you please post a small complete code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Is a LyX file also acceptable?

Comment: We need  a latex code. I  don't have Lyx installed.

Comment: Ok, then I have to figure this out first.

Comment: Done, I stripped my Lyx document to necessary minimum, added LaTeX code and modified original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think now they are close enough.

[image: x2]

Add this code to your preamble and remove the `flushleft` from the package options.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\TPT@doparanotes}{\par
    \prevdepth\z@ \TPT@hsize
    \TPTnoteSettings
    \parindent\z@ \pretolerance 8
    \linepenalty 200
    \renewcommand\item[1][]{\relax\ifhmode \begingroup
        \unskip
        \advance\hsize 10em % \hsize is scratch register, based on real hsize
        \penalty -45 \hskip\z@\@plus\hsize \penalty-19
        \hskip .15\hsize \penalty 9999 \hskip-.15\hsize
        \hskip .01\hsize\@plus-\hsize\@minus.01\hsize 
        \hskip -0.5em\@plus .3em   %% changed from 1em to -0.5em
        \endgroup\fi
        \tnote{##1}\,\ignorespaces}%
    \let\TPToverlap\relax
    \def\endtablenotes{\par}%
}
\makeatother
```

Even more compact. Although still five lines.

[image: x3]

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\TPT@doparanotes}{\par
    \prevdepth\z@ \TPT@hsize
    \TPTnoteSettings
    \parindent\z@ \pretolerance 8
    \linepenalty 200
    \renewcommand\item[1][]{\relax\ifhmode \begingroup
        \unskip
        \advance\hsize 10em % \hsize is scratch register, based on real hsize
        \penalty -45 \hskip\z@\@plus\hsize \penalty-19
        \hskip .15\hsize \penalty 9999 \hskip-.15\hsize
        \hskip .008\hsize\@plus-\hsize\@minus.01\hsize %% changed 
        \hskip -0.2em\@plus .1em %% changed 
        \endgroup\fi
        \tnote{##1}\,\ignorespaces}%
    \let\TPToverlap\relax
    \def\endtablenotes{\par}%
}
\makeatother
```